# Script to retrieve new YouTube videos

Tags: python, youtube

I wrote a script which retrieves YouTube videos from your favourite channels - channels you specify in a .txt file. Let me know what you think about it.

**Channel and Video classes**

```
import urllib.request
import json
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#**************
apiKey = #Insert your Youtube API key.
#**************

youtubeApiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3"
youtubeChannelsApiUrl = youtubeApiUrl + "/channels?key={0}&".format(apiKey)
youtubeSearchApiUrl = youtubeApiUrl + "/search?key={0}&".format(apiKey)
youtubeVideoApi = youtubeApiUrl +"/videos?key={0}&".format(apiKey)

requestParametersChannelId = youtubeChannelsApiUrl + 'forUsername={0}&part=id' 
requestChannelVideosInfo = youtubeSearchApiUrl + 'channelId={0}&part=id&order=date&type=video&publishedBefore={1}&publishedAfter={2}&pageToken={3}&maxResults=50'
requestVideoInfo = youtubeVideoApi + "part=snippet&id={0}"
requestVideoTime = youtubeVideoApi +"part=contentDetails&id={0}"

class Channel:

    def __init__(self, channelName, channelAlias=None, channelId=None):

        self.channelName = channelName
        self.channelAlias = channelAlias
        self.channelId = channelId

    def __str__(self):
         return "Channel name:  {}\nChannel Alias:  {}\nChannelId:  {}".format(self.channelName,
                                                                             self.channelAlias,
                                                                             self.channelId)

    def __repr__(self):
         return "Channel name:  {}\nChannel Alias:  {}\nChannelId:  {}".format(self.channelName,
                                                                             self.channelAlias,
                                                                             self.channelId)


    def setChannelId(self):
        try:
            url = requestParametersChannelId.format(self.channelName)
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf8")

            jsonResp = json.loads(resp)
            self.channelId = jsonResp["items"][0]["id"]
        except IndexError:
            print("ERROR setting ID for channel: {}".format(self.channelName))
            self.channelId = "error"





    def _getVideosBetween(self,  sinceDate, toDate):
        """
        dates= datetime.datetime objects
        """
        #format dates
        sinceDate = sinceDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        toDate = toDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

        nextPToken = ""
        foundAll = False

        retVal = []

        while not foundAll:
            try:
                url = requestChannelVideosInfo.format(self.channelId, toDate, sinceDate, nextPToken)
                resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf8")


                jsonResp = json.loads(resp)
                returnedVideos = jsonResp["items"]

                for video in returnedVideos:
                    retVal.append(video["id"]["videoId"])

                try:
                    nextPToken = jsonResp["nextPageToken"]

                except: #no nextPageToken
                    foundAll = True

            except IndexError: #error; no videos found. dont print anything
                foundAll = True

        return retVal

    def getLastXDaysVideos(self, last_x_days):
        todayDate = datetime.now()
        previousDate = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=last_x_days)

        return self._getVideosBetween(previousDate, todayDate)


    def getVideosSince(self, sinceDate):
        """
        sinceDate = datetime.datetime object
        """

        todayDate = datetime.now()
        return self._getVideosBetween(sinceDate, todayDate)

    def getAllVideos(self):
        firstDate = datetime(year=2005, month=4, day=22) #first youtube video -1
        todayDate = datetime.now()

        return self._getVideosBetween(firstDate, todayDate)



class Video:
    def __init__(self, videoId):
        self.videoId = videoId

    def getData(self, parseDuration=True, parseDate=True):
        try:
            results = {}
            url = requestVideoInfo.format(self.videoId)
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf8")


            jsonResp = json.loads(resp)
            results["title"] = jsonResp["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]
            results["date"] = jsonResp["items"][0]["snippet"]["publishedAt"]
            results["description"] = jsonResp["items"][0]["snippet"]["description"]
            results["url"] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(self.videoId)

            #need to create different request for duration
            url = requestVideoTime.format(self.videoId)
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf8")   
            jsonResp = json.loads(resp)
            duration = jsonResp["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["duration"]

            if parseDuration:
                #parses iso 8601 duration manually
                digits = re.findall(r"\d+", duration)
                times = ["seconds", "minutes", "hours"]
                res = []

                for digit, time in zip(digits[::-1], times):
                    res.append("{} {},".format(digit, time))

                res.reverse() #start with biggest unit
                parsedDuration = " ".join(res)[:-1] #omit last colon
                results["duration"] = parsedDuration
            else:
                results["duration"] = duration

            if parseDate:
                #2016-12-17T14:54:05.000Z --> 14:54  12.12.2016
                digits = re.findall(r"\d+", results["date"])
                parsedDate = "{hours}:{minutes}  {day}.{month}.{year}".format(
                    hours=digits[3], minutes=digits[4], day=digits[2], month=digits[1], year=digits[0]
                    )

                results["date"] = parsedDate

            #no need for else as unparsed date is already in results dict
            return results


        except IndexError:
            print("ERROR: Finding video data for video {}".format(self.videoId))
            return None
```

**Channel Feed**

```
from youtube_api import *


FILENAME = "channels.txt"

def process_file(filename):
    """
    returns tuple(
        datetime object,
        dictionary - channel:id
        )

    """
    channels = {}

    with open(FILENAME, "r+") as f:    
        #2016 12 17   19 29
        #tuple to create datetime object
        date = [int(i) for i in f.readline().strip().split()]
        _ = f.readline() #consume newline
        lines = f.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            try: #explicit channel Id
                channelName, channelId = line.strip().split(" ### ")
                channels[channelName] = channelId
            except:
                channelName = line.strip()
                channels[channelName] = 0

        currDate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y %m %d   %H %M")
        f.seek(0)        
        f.write(currDate)


    date_obj = datetime(*date) #unpack tuple with date
    return (date_obj, channels)


def main():
    date, channels = process_file(FILENAME)
    print("Last checked: {}".format(date.strftime("%H:%M  %d.%m.%Y")))
    for channelName, chId in sorted(channels.items()): #alphabetical order
        #create Channel objects for every channel, assign an ID unless explicitly specified in file
        if chId == 0:
            chan = Channel(channelName)
            chan.setChannelId()
        else:
            chan = Channel(channelName, channelId=chId)


        print("\n" + "*" * 40 +" \n{}\n".format(channelName) + "*" * 40)
        videos = chan.getVideosSince(date)
        for videoId in videos:
           vid = Video(videoId)
           data = vid.getData()
           try:
               print("   {}\n   {} ; {}\n   {}\n   {}\n\n".format(data["title"], data["date"],data["duration"], data["url"], data["description"].split("\n")[0]))
           except: #unicode error (not running in IDLE)
               print("   {}\n   {}\n   {}\n    \n    -Unable to display more informtaion\n\n".format(data["date"], data["duration"], data["url"]))
        if len(videos) == 0:
           print("   No videos found in this time period :(\n")


    i = input("\nPress enter to exit. ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General remark: your `try/except` blocks without any arguments are bad: if anything happens (including syntax error, ...) your exception block is called. It would be better to narrow down the block to the exceptions you're expecting:

```
try:
   (some code)
except (ValueError, NameError):
     pass
```

Channel and video classes:

This is cumbersome and inefficient, you're accessing the same dict keys over and over:

```
jsonResp = json.loads(resp)
results["title"] = jsonResp["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]
results["date"] = jsonResp["items"][0]["snippet"]["publishedAt"]
results["description"] = jsonResp["items"][0]["snippet"]["description"]
```

I'd do:

```
jsonResp = json.loads(resp)
response_items = jsonResp["items"][0]  # you can reuse it below
snippet = response_items["snippet"]
results["title"] = snippet["title"]
results["date"] = snippet["publishedAt"]
results["description"] = snippet
```

Also, this part of channel feed needs improving:

```
_ = f.readline() #consume newline
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    try: #explicit channel Id
        channelName, channelId = line.strip().split(" ### ")
        channels[channelName] = channelId
    except:
        channelName = line.strip()
        channels[channelName] = 0
```

`_ = f.readline() #consume newline` is better written as `next(f)`. Then don't use `readlines`, just iterate on `f`. You'll save time storing data you don't need.

I'd rewrite that as:

```
next(f) #consume newline

for line in f:  # iterate on file lines
    try: #explicit channel Id
        channelName, channelId = line.strip().split(" ### ")
        channels[channelName] = channelId
    except ValueError: # too many values to unpack can happen
        channelName = line.strip()
        channels[channelName] = 0
```

Still, the `seek` in the end to write the new date works, although that's a really weird way to timestamp a file. I would just read the file, then open as `append` and close to update timestamp, and use `os.path.getmtime()` to get last modification time. That way you don't have to store the date in the file, and use read/write on a text file, which is risky.

Comment: Thanks for extensive analysis of my code! All of your remarks are absolutely on point, and I already updated my code to follow them. One more question though.

Comment: Nvm, got it. Cheers!